# Windows => Webdav folders are empty, when it contains an HTML file

Tags: html, windows, .htaccess, webdav

I'm experiencing a very weird behavior on Windows 7. I've included a WebDav server (Apache) into my Windows Explorer (Map Network Drive).

Every folder works fine and Windows displays all contents correctly... until I add an HTML file to that folder, then Windows is not able to display the contents of the folder anymore. First it shows an empty folder and then it tells me that the "disc might be corrupt". As soon as I remove the html file on the server, everything is working fine again.

So for some reason WebDav tries to interpret the HTML files (As it does when I visit that folder from a browser). I've already created an .htaccess file that contains the following, but that didn't help.

`RemoveHandler .html
RemoveType .html`

Do you guys have any idea what might be causing this?

Thank you very much in advance,

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

I just added DirectoryIndex disabled to the VirtualHost! :)